# Question 10.9 from Bayesian Data Analysis, what does accuracy mean here?

Tags: self-study, bayesian, accuracy

I'm doing an independent study in Bayesian Statistics following some chapters from [BDA3](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/book/). When solving the first question from Ch 10 I got stuck. It says:

> [If] a scalar variable $\theta$ is approximately normally distributed in a posterior distribution that is summarized by *n* independent simulation draws [,] how large does *n* have to be so that the 2.5% and 97.5% quantiles of $\theta$ are specified to an accuracy of $0.1\ {\rm sd}(\theta|y)$?

Just by following the formula for a numerical example in the same chapter I get $n=100$, but I do not understand actually what they mean by **accuracy** in this context.

Any pointers?